# Check if firebase has finished adding items to database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sending data from my android app to a realtime firebase database.

I would like to check when firebase has finished adding these items into the database, as I will be calling a script on the server that will access the data in the database (through an asynctask).

But before I call the script, I need to make sure that firebase has finished adding all the items as to avoid any conflicts in the data. The code would be something like this:

```
myRef.child(userID).setValue(items); //add items to firebase database

new SendPostRequest().execute(); //call script on the server that will connect 
                                    to firebase database and retrieve data.
```

I was wondering if the script would be called whilst firebase is adding data to the database therefore it would retrieve partial data, so I need to make sure that firebase has finished adding the items into the database first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a completion listener to `setValue()` to get notified when the call has completed.

See the section [add a completion callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) in the Firebase documentation for a full example.

> ```
> mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
>     .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
>             // Write was successful!
>             // ...
>         }
>     })
>     ...
> ```